Bidual vs a GNS Representation
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra and $\varphi_0$ a state on it.
Let $f_1\in \mathcal{A}$ be self-adjoint with spectrum $\sigma(f_1)$. Let $\sigma(f_1)=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^nE_i$ be a partition of $\sigma(f_1)$ into Borel sets. Spectral projections $\mathbf{1}_{E_i}(f_1)$ exist in the bidual $\mathcal{A}^{**}$.
Attach a label $\lambda_i$ to each $E_i$ and we can form a finite-spectrum version of $f_1\in\mathcal{A}$ in $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ by:
$$\widetilde{f_1}=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i \mathbf{1}_{E_i}(f_1).$$
Now I want to interpret $\varphi_0$ as the initial state of a system, and given the state $\varphi_0$ I measure it with $\widetilde{f_1}$. To do this take the $\sigma$-weakly continuous extension $\omega_0:\mathcal{A}^{**}\to \mathbb{C}$ of $\varphi_0$.
Now we interpret $\widetilde{f_1}$ as a random variable with distribution $\omega_0$, with
$$\mathbb{P}[\widetilde{f_1}=\lambda_j]=\omega_0(\mathbf{1}_{E_j}(f_1))\implies \mathbb{E}[\widetilde{f_1}]=\omega(\widetilde{f_1}).$$
Now, if we somehow observe $\widetilde{f_1}=\lambda_j$ (requires $\mathbb{P}[\widetilde{f_1}=\lambda_j]>0$), we will see wave-function collapse to $\varphi_1$, a state on $\mathcal{A}$ given by:
$$\varphi_1(g)=\dfrac{\omega_0(\mathbf{1}_{E_j}(f_1) g\mathbf{1}_{E_j}(f_1))}{\omega_0(\mathbf{1}_{E_j}(f_1))}\qquad (g\in \mathcal{A}).$$
Now we can take another self-adjoint $f_2\in\mathcal{A}$, produce a finite spectrum version of it and measure $\varphi_1$ with it. We get some result $\widetilde{f_2}=\mu_\ell$, and collapse $\varphi_1\to \varphi_2$. We continue by measuring with finite-spectrum $\widetilde{f_2},\widetilde{f_3},\dots$ of self-adjoint $f_2,\,f_3,\dots\in\mathcal{A}$, and we produce a sequence of states $(\varphi_i)_{=0}^m$. We call this the sequential measurement by $\widetilde{f_m}$ after $\widetilde{f_{m-1}}$ after... after $\widetilde{f_2}$ after $\widetilde{f_1}$ and denote by:
$$\widetilde{f_m}\succ \widetilde{f_{m-1}}\succ \cdots \succ f_2\succ f_1.$$

So, we have a pair $(\mathcal{A},\varphi_0)$, and we produce a sequence of states [Note 1] $(\varphi_i)_{=0}^m\subset \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$. We have to get the spectral projections of self-adjoint $f\in \mathcal{A}$. But can we instead use a GNS representation to do this?
So, (dropping the zero for notational reasons) take $(\mathcal{A},\varphi)$ and produce a GNS representation $\pi_{\varphi}(\mathcal{A})\subset B(\mathsf{H}_\varphi)$ with cyclic vector $x_\varphi$ and we have:
$$\varphi(g)=\langle x_{\varphi},\pi_{\varphi}(g)x_{\varphi}\rangle\qquad (g\in \mathcal{A}).$$
Can we do all this sequential measurement business in $\pi_\varphi(\mathcal{A})''$? The state $\varphi$ is now given as a vector state. Is the (appropriately topological) extension of the vector state to a state on $\pi_\varphi(\mathcal{A})''$ given by the same formula (I believe it is)? We can produce a finite spectrum version of $\pi_{\varphi}(f)$ given by $\widetilde{\pi_\varphi(f)}$. Does this respect the previously calculated probabilities? Let $P_{E_i}(\pi_\varphi(f))$ be the spectral projection in $\pi_\varphi(\mathcal{A})''$ associated with $E_i\subset \sigma(f)$. Do these objects play nice enough with the spectrum so that if for $\omega:\mathcal{A}^{**}\to \mathbb{C}$ the $\sigma$-weak extension of $\varphi:\mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{C}$, we have, for maybe $E\subset \sigma(f)$ the largest Borel set with $\omega(\mathbf{1}_E(f))=0$ we have maybe $P_E(\pi_\varphi(f))=0$ or $E\cap \sigma_{\pi_\varphi(\mathcal{A})}(f)=\emptyset$, or whatever makes for all Borel $E_i\subset \sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(f)$:
$$\omega(\mathbf{1}_{E_i}(f))=\langle x_\varphi,P_{E_i}(\pi_\varphi(f)) x_\varphi \rangle ?$$
And can we just do Born's Rule $x_\varphi\to x_1$, where $x_1:=P_{E_j}((\pi_\varphi(f)))x_\varphi/\|P_{E_j}((\pi_\varphi(f)))x_\varphi\|^2$ to implement the conditioned state and preserve the probabilities? So, where $\varphi_1$ is, for some spectral projection $p\in\mathcal{A}^{**}$ of self-adjoint $f\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\omega(p)>0$
$$\varphi_1(g)=\dfrac{\omega(pgp)}{\omega(p)}\qquad (g\in\mathcal{A}),$$
the extensions $\omega_1$ and the vector state $x_1$ agree on the spectral projections $\mathbf{1}_E(f_2)\in\mathcal{A}^{**}$ and $P_E(\pi_\varphi(f_2))$ for $E\subset \sigma_\mathcal{A}(f_2)$ of self-adjoint $f_2\in\mathcal{A}$?
$$\omega_1(\mathbf{1}_E(f_2))=\langle x_1,P_E(\pi_\varphi(f_2))x_1\rangle?$$

Question: What are objections to using the bidual to get spectral projections, and does using the double commutant $\pi_\varphi(\mathcal{A})''$ via $(\pi_\varphi,\mathsf{H}_\varphi,x_\varphi)$ like this get around these objections?


[Note 1] just for context, this approach can be used to provide conceptual proofs in the field I work in. To give a flavour, we have that if for all initial states $\varphi_0$ on a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra, there exists a finite sequence of self-adjoint $f_k\in\mathcal{A}$ such that the sequential measurement $f_m\succ \cdots f_1$ is such that, with probability one, $\varphi_m$ is a character, then $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative, and this approach can be used to give conceptual proofs of commutativity of some universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras (with finite dimensional abelianisations). It is worth noting that in many of these examples I have been able to find the sequence of measurements as projections in the $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra, somehow trivialising the above question.

They are the same thing. There is a natural normal $\ast$-homomorphism $\varphi’’$ from $A^{\ast\ast}$ to $\pi_\varphi(A)’’$ extending $\pi_\varphi$, and normal $\ast$-homomorphisms commute with Borel functional calculus (so in particular with your operation of producing finite spectrum version of elements). The unique normal extension of $\varphi$ then coincide with $\varphi’’$ composed with the vector state associated to $x_\varphi$ (since both are normal and coincide on $A$, which is weakly dense).

And yes, $\varphi_1 = \omega(p\cdot p)/\omega(p)$ coincides with the vector state generated by (the normalization of) $\varphi’’(p)x_\varphi$ (or, more precisely, the composition of this vector state with $\varphi’’$), which can be easily shown by just a direct calculation.

The moral here, really, is that while not technically true, $A^{\ast\ast}$ is effectively just the direct sum of all $\pi_\varphi(A)’’$, so doing things in $A^{\ast\ast}$ is basically no different from doing those things in $\pi_\varphi(A)’’$ for all $\varphi$ simultaneously. If you just care about a single $\varphi$, then it doesn’t matter whether you do it in $A^{\ast\ast}$ or $\pi_\varphi(A)’’$.

@DavidGao thank you. Are you aware of objections to using the bidual over this GNS representation?

I’m not sure if this is specifically what you are referring to, but I do sometimes hear people being reluctant to use biduals. It seems one of the reasons is simply that not many people are familiar with it, and it’s also quite technical and defined somewhat abstractly, so people are understandably unwilling to use a technical tool they don’t fully understand. The other reason is that biduals are rarely separable, even when $A$ is. (Here, when I say a vNa is separable, I meant that it can be faithfully represented on a separable Hilbert space, not that it is separable under the weak$^\ast$…

… topology. The latter would always be true when $A$ is separable as a $C^\ast$-algebra.) Indeed, as long as $A$ contains a copy of $C([0,1])$ (or continuous functions on any uncountable space, for that matter), $A^{\ast\ast}$ will be non-separable. This would not happen for the double commutant of a GNS representation, which will always be separable as long as $A$ is.

If you would like to convert these comments into an answer, I will accept.

Here are my comments, turned into an answer:
They are the same thing. There is a unique normal $\ast$-homomorphism $\pi_\varphi''$ from $A^{\ast\ast}$ to $\pi_\varphi(A)''$ extending $\pi_\varphi$, and normal $\ast$-homomorphisms commute with Borel functional calculus (so in particular with your operation of producing finite spectrum versions of elements). The unique normal extension of $\varphi$ then coincides with $\pi_\varphi''$ composed with the vector state associated to $x_\varphi$, since both are normal and coincide on $A$, which is weakly dense. And yes, $\varphi_1 = \omega(p \cdot p)/\omega(p)$ coincides with the vector state generated by (the normalization of) $\pi_\varphi''(p)x_\varphi$, or, more precisely, the composition of this vector state with $\pi_\varphi''$, which can be easily shown by a direct calculation.
The moral here, really, is that while not technically true, $A^{\ast\ast}$ is effectively just the direct sum of all $\pi_\varphi(A)''$, so doing things in $A^{\ast\ast}$ is basically no different from doing those things in $\pi_\varphi(A)''$ for all $\varphi$ simultaneously. If you just care about a single $\varphi$, then it doesn't matter whether you do it in $A^{\ast\ast}$ or $\pi_\varphi(A)''$.
As for objections to using biduals, I do sometimes hear people being reluctant to use them. It seems one of the reasons is simply that not many people are familiar with them, and they're also quite technical and defined somewhat abstractly, so people are understandably unwilling to use a technical tool they don't fully understand. The other reason is that biduals are rarely separable, even when $A$ is. (Here, when I say a von Neumann algebra is separable, I meant that it can be faithfully represented on a separable Hilbert space, not that it is separable under the weak$^\ast$ topology. The latter would always be true when $A$ is separable as a $C^\ast$-algebra.) Indeed, as long as $A$ contains a copy of $C([0,1])$ (or the algebra of continuous functions vanishing at infinity on any uncountable LCH space, for that matter), $A^{\ast\ast}$ will be non-separable. This would not happen for the double commutant of a GNS representation, which will always be separable as long as $A$ is.
